# Why does SortedList in C# have no Find method?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, data-structures, sortedlist

Silly if you ask me. But this message is here because I will assume (probably correctly) that I am the silly one, not Microsoft. So... is there something I'm missing? Why didn't they include a "Find" method to this baby? The find could work on the Values, which are objects, so then I could do this:

```
someObject = SortedList.Values.Find(order => order.OrderID == orderID);
```

Comment: Sorted lists are designed to support efficient lookup using the key. If you need to search the list using other criteria, then it may be a good idea to use the `OrderID` as the key in the list, perhaps (unless you need this only very rarely...)?

Comment: I got the List sorted by DateTime. This is why I used a SortedList.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be looking for `.First(...)` or `.Single(...)` (or their `OrDefault` variants) in LINQ, but that only really works well with types that implement `IEnumerable<T>`. A `SortedList` is not strongly typed, hence the Lambda won't work. Have a look at LINQ's `.Cast<T>()`.

Comment: I use no LINQ in this project. IndexOfKey is not useful. I am looking for a certain object with a certain ID.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want:

```
SortedList.Values.Cast<Order>().FirstOrDefault(order => order.OrderID == orderID);
```

Of couse, if you are talking about `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`, the call to `Cast()` is unnecessary.

Btw, if you are poking through the `Values` of a `SortedList` in that manner, there is a good chance you're using a poor choice for the key / using the wrong data-structure altogether.

**EDIT:**

If you can't use LINQ in the project, nor do you wish to maintain separate data-structures keyed by the order's date and orderID respectively (as suggested by Ben Voigt), I see no choice but to implement the search yourself:

```
foreach(ShopOrder order in sortedList.Values)
{
  if(order.OrderID == orderID) return order;
}

return null; // or throw an exception, whichever you find appropriate.
```

If you want to generalize further, write your own `FirstOrDefault` implementation.

Comment: My declaration is 

SortedList<DateTime, ShopOrder> orders = new SortedList<DateTime, ShopOrder>(comparer);

The comparer is a simple DateTime comparer. I got more orders and I need to sort them by DateTime but I also want to quickly find an order ID. I think it's the right structure to use. And I do not use LINQ btw, so I see no "FirstOrDefault" ::- (.

Comment: @ Axonn - At least in a time-complexity sense, you cannot 'quickly' find an orderID with this data-structure. Btw, Is there any reason you can't use LINQ? Are you on a a version prior to .NET 3.5?

Comment: Then you might want two collections: a `SortedList<DateTime, ShopOrder>` and a `Dictionary<int, ShopOrder>` that lets you easily lookup based on the ID.

Comment: @Axonn: Even if you can’t use the “real” LINQ, you can trivially write a `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` method yourself: http://csharp.pastebin.com/zuPB2kbn

Comment: Eventually I coded a method that sorts a normal list and that's it ::- D. Thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Are you searching on the same field that the list is sorted by?  A binary search would be fastest, and `SortedList` provides the [`IndexOfKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.indexofkey.aspx) function to do that.

It looks like you're searching through the values, in which case using LINQ's `FirstOrDefault` on the result of [`GetValueList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.getvaluelist.aspx) should work.

See also: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/55241049-7e7e-4006-8e04-70779698d609

Comment: I use no LINQ in this project. IndexOfKey is not useful. I am looking for a certain object with a certain ID.